# WordPress: Is it possible to have "rss content" AS the "post" itself on blog.wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress

I think the title describes my question perfectly. I have a blog on something.wordpress.com . I want to make a post, but the post should be **JUST** `rss` content sourced from a feed I specify.

(a) can I do that?
(b) can i do that on wordpress.com or do i need to setup my own **wordpress** installation?
(c) is there a service somewhere that lets me **EMBED** these `rss` feeds into my post?

Just found these sites that demonstrate what I'm talking about better!

http://popurls.com/
http://alltop.com/

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/110721/wordpress-is-it-possible-to-have-rss-content-as-the-post-itself-on-blog-word

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_content_rss(); ?>
```

[Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content_rss)